# Why would babel-register results differ from babel (pre-transpiled)?

Tags: javascript, mocking, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

With the same source code, I get different runtime results pre-transpiling with babel vs. transpiling with babel-register on the fly.
When the pre-transpiled code runs, it operates correctly.
When the code transpiles with babel-register it fails.

Same results in Node 4.2 and 5.10

Working:

```
babel ./ --ignore='node_modules/*,output/*' -d output
mocha output/tests/unit --recursive --reporter spec
```

Not Working:

```
mocha tests/unit --recursive --reporter spec --compilers js:babel-register
```

347 tests at the moment.

When it fails, only 2 of the tests fail, and they fail the exact same way -  Trying to `require` a file (different files).
AFAICT, the failing test suites and the files they are `require`ing don’t have anything special or differentiating about them.

#### More Detail

- The test suite uses [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) to hook the loader to substitute mocks at require time.
- The test suite uses mockery in the same fashion 21 times total, but only fails 2 uses.
- The test suites are still in es5.
- At the line of error, the module 'require`d is not mocked and is es6. The mocks that are subsequently required from that es6 file are in es5. So es5 requires es6 which requires es5 mocks. This is how all 21 tests are run.
- I also tried prefixing the failing command with `env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1`

The symptomatic babel error is `"Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined"`

Looking at the specific error in babel, it appears that a WeakMap reference `cache.path` is undefined when its `delete` method is called.
I don’t yet understand HOW that object reference could possibly be removed.

Error Stack:

```
/test-project/services/data/fetch.js: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined
  at traverse.clearNode (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:151:13)
  at Function.traverse.cheap (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:86:3)
  at Function.traverse.removeProperties (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:161:12)
  at getAst (node_modules/babel-template/lib/index.js:63:40)
  at node_modules/babel-template/lib/index.js:85:24
  at PluginPass.exit (node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/lib/index.js:308:33)
  at newFn (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:262:19)
  at NodePath._call (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:63:18)
  at NodePath.call (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:47:17)
  at NodePath.visit (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:105:8)
  at TraversalContext.visitQueue (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:152:16)
  at TraversalContext.visitSingle (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:115:19)
  at TraversalContext.visit (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:184:19)
  at Function.traverse.node (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:135:17)
  at Object.traverse [as default] (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:69:12)
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:513:33
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at File.transform (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:510:23)
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:49:19
  at File.wrap (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:528:16)
  at Pipeline.transform (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:17)
  at Object.transformFileSync (node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/node.js:124:10)
  at compile (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:98:20)
  at loader (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:126:14)
  at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
  at Function.hookedLoader [as _load] (node_modules/mockery/mockery.js:111:12)
  at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
  at Context.<anonymous> (tests/unit/services/data/fetch.js:21:13)
  at Object.exports.default (node_modules/babel-template/lib/index.js:46:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/lib/index.js:37:56)
  at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:134:7)
  at Function.hookedLoader [as _load] (node_modules/mockery/mockery.js:111:12)
  at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/index.js:22:5)
  at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:134:7)
  at Function.hookedLoader [as _load] (node_modules/mockery/mockery.js:111:12)
  at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:22
  at Array.map (native)
  at OptionManager.resolvePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:364:20)
  at OptionManager.mergePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:348:10)
  at OptionManager.mergeOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:307:14)
  at OptionManager.addConfig (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:207:10)
  at OptionManager.findConfigs (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:413:16)
  at OptionManager.init (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:461:12)
  at compile (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:81:45)
  at loader (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:126:14)
  at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
  at Function.hookedLoader [as _load] (node_modules/mockery/mockery.js:111:12)
  at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
  at Context.<anonymous> (tests/unit/services/data/fetch.js:21:13)
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: are you using export default in your code?

Comment: Yes (in the es6 modules being required).

Comment: should have asked this too... does that file also have the delete ?

Comment: no there is no `delete` anywhere in that code

Comment: ok, can you try this for me?  In the file where the require is failing, do this: `require('./yourRequireFile').default();`

Comment: I get the exact same error. double checked I was running what I thought I was running, too. Also tried it on the mock - same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue.

Here's what was happening:

1. My app requires a module via path './cache' (I have a module named cache.js)
2. Babel-traverse/index.js requires its own cache module (a WeakMap) via path './cache'.
3. My failing tests mock my cache require using './cache' as a module identifier.
4. The './cache' mocks were also being returned to babel when it `require('./cache')`.

Once the mock was setup (loader hooked), my mock for './cache' was being returned to babel-traverse when it required './cache'. My cache implementation does not export a WeakMap, so no 'delete' method is there. Good thing, or I would have had an even more obscure problem.

[Matching on module identifier or path is just how mockery works](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery#registering-mocks).

This also explains why it worked precompiling babel and not running babel on the fly. On the fly, while the tests are run, the mockery loader hook is in effect.

Using mockery with babel is a tricky business. If you must do this:

1. If you have to use babel-register (transpiling on the fly) make sure your module identifiers (the paths you require that you might mock) are unique to your app, or you might be supplying your mocks to babel as well.
2. If you can, just pre-transpile using babel cli.

Anytime you are playing with globals you are playing with fire.